# Proof that the middle-thirds Cantor set has no isolated points

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

> Let $x_0$ be some point in the Cantor set $C$. Prove that $\forall\epsilon>0\, \exists y\in C$ such that $y\neq x_0$ and $|x_0 - y|<\epsilon$.

Comment: @AlexR I think you mean perfect -equal to its derived set/accumulation points's set-

Comment: @JosuéTonelli-Cueto Yes that was it. Sorry.

Comment: @JosuéTonelli-Cueto : This is also not the same as proving the Cantor set is perfect (although it is).  The set of all rational numbers also shares the property to be proved, but that set is certainly not perfect.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Yes, you are rigth. However, I said that because it is immediate that the Cantor set is closed -in the usual interval construction-.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

In the $n$-th step of constructions the remaining numbers in one interval are (weakly) closer than $\dfrac1{3^n}$.

Answer (score 0):

The Cantor set consists of all points on $[0,1]$ that can be represented as a "decimal" in base 3 without using the digit 1.  For example, 
$0.0212 = \frac{23}{81} \not \in C$ becasue it has a 1 in the $3^{-3}$ place.

Let the representation of $x_0$ in base three have digits (trigits?) $x_i$ for all $i \in \Bbb{N}$, and choose integer $k$ large enough that $\epsilon > 3^{-k}$.   Then choose a representation of $y$ as 
$$\begin{array}{cc} \forall i \leq k : & y_i = x_i \\
\forall i > k : & y_i = 2-x_i 
\end{array}
$$

Then since there are no ones among the $x_i$ there are also no ones among the $y_i$, so the number $y$ represented by the "decimal" sequence (tresimal?) $y_i$ is an element of $C$.

And $|x_0 - y| < 3^{-k} < \epsilon$.